# For loop to change multiple dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop

I am analysing single-cell RNA sequencing. I have been trying to do a for loop to make add information to the metadata from different samples. I want to avoid repeating the same functions as below.

```
metadata_sample_1$true_doublets = factor(metadata_sample_1$true_doublets)
metadata_sample_2$true_doublets = factor(metadata_sample_2$true_doublets)
metadata_sample_3$true_doublets = factor(metadata_sample_3$true_doublets)
metadata_sample_4$true_doublets = factor(metadata_sample_4$true_doublets)

metadata_sample_1$Barcode = rownames(metadata_sample_1)
metadata_sample_2$Barcode = rownames(metadata_sample_2)
metadata_sample_3$Barcode = rownames(metadata_sample_3)
metadata_sample_4$Barcode = rownames(metadata_sample_4)

df.sample_1 = merge(colData(sample_1), metadata_sample_1, by = "Barcode")
df.sample_2 = merge(colData(sample_2), metadata_sample_2, by = "Barcode")
df.sample_3 = merge(colData(sample_3), metadata_sample_3, by = "Barcode")
df.sample_4 = merge(colData(sample_4), metadata_sample_4, by = "Barcode")

colData(sample_1)$doublet = df.sample_1$true_doublets
colData(sample_2)$doublet = df.sample_2$true_doublets
colData(sample_3)$doublet = df.sample_3$true_doublets
colData(sample_4)$doublet = df.sample_4$true_doublets
```

I have tried to create a function that will do this but I don't think I'm doing it right

```
asing_column = function(sce, dataset, column = true_doublets) {
  dataset %>%
    mutate(column== as.factor(column))
  dataset$Barcode = rownames(dataset)
  data.fr = merge(colData(sce), dataset, by = "Barcode")
  assign(data.fr, paste0("df",sce, sep = "_"))
  return(data.fr)
}
```

and

```
metadata= list(metadata_sample_1, metadata_sample_2, metadata_sample_3,metadata_sample_4)
for (i in metadata){
 i %>%
    mutate_at("true_doublets", factor)
  str(i)
}
```

Comment: Put all your dataframes in a list then iterate over the list.

Comment: is this Deseq2?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have two lists. one containing metadata and one containing the samples themselves? (not sure why your data is like this, it makes everything more complex this way. Isn't colData the metadata? (of SummarizedExperiment))

Anyways, lists should have the pairs at the same position. (ie metadata[[1]] belongs to samples[[1]] etc..)

```
metadata= list(metadata_sample_1, metadata_sample_2, metadata_sample_3,metadata_sample_4)
samples = list(sample_1,sample_2,sample_3,sample_4)
```

write a function to do the merging ( i am trying to avoid to assign the intermediate result from merge to an object i.e. `df.sample_X` / `data.fr`, since this will just use space. And `true_doublets` is the only relevant vector.

```
mergeBarcode <- function(sample,metadata) {
  metadata$true_doublets = factor(metadata$true_doublets)
  metadata$Barcode = rownames(metadata)
  colData(sample)$doublet = merge(colData(sample), metadata, by = "Barcode")$true_doublets
}
```

iterate over both lists and use the function.

```
for (i in 1:length(samples)) {
  mergeBarcode(samples[[i]],metadata[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have tried the function you suggested but it does not work. I do not see an error code when I run it so I don't think it has do to with the function itself. I have tried to run it outside the function and it works. I am working with  an S4 object for single cell RNA seq using bio conductor, to access the data frame I use colData.Not sure if it is related.